# Почему ячейки отбиваются друг от друга если удалить border в класса row, хотя margin задан исключительно тегу h1. И должен срабатывать только на h1

Tags: border, margin

Почему, когда я удаляю border, который присвоен классам row, все ячейки начинают отбиваться друг от друга? Ведь margin: 60px 0px 20px 50px; присвоен только к h1, т.е margin должен срабатывать только к тегу h1 и весь текст внутри данного тега должен отбиваться от границ div'a row.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напшите код в вопросе, нам что самим его переписывать?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1424115/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%8f%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-border-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b0-row-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-ma